Did Draco Malfoy know that Sirius had betrayed Harry's parents?
When Draco asked Harry why he wasn't hunting for Sirius, the only explanation I can think of here is that he believed (just like Lupin) that Sirius betrayed Harry's parents and therefore Harry should take revenge. But how could Draco know such details that were not common knowledge (Fudge mentioned to Rosmerta in the Three Broomsticks)?

But Malfoy's eyes were shining malevolently, and they were fixed
Harry. He leaned across the table.
"Thinking of trying to catch Black single-handed, Potter?"
"Yeah, that's right," said Harry offhandedly.
Malfoy's thin mouth was curving in a mean smile.
"Of course, if it was me," he said quietly, "I'd have done something
before now. I wouldn't be staying in school like a good boy, I'd be
out there looking for him."
"What are you talking about, Malfoy?" said Ron roughly.
"Don't you know, Potter?" breathed Malfoy, his pale eyes narrowed.
"Know what?"
Malfoy let out a low, sneering laugh.
"Maybe you'd rather not risk your neck," he said. "Want to leave it to
the Dementors, do you? But if it was me, I'd want revenge. I'd hunt
him down myself."


@AcePL Sirius was sent in without a trial. Even Rosmerta the owner of three broomstick, who lived in all wizard village, didn't know about Sirius being Potter's secret keeper.

Right you are. He was imprisoned without trial and the fact that he was the secret keeper was not widely known. But it was not a secret - otherwise the ruse with switching the secret keeper from Sirius to Peter would have no point whatsoever. Since the way Fidelius Charm works we knowthat  there were a number of Secret Keepers for Potters, all of whom could, after their death, divulge that information. How Malfoy found out is not explained, but one can safely assume that MoM was at some point informed of that fact, inevitably finding a way to Malfoy's ear sooner or later.
